# useEffect Hook not triggered after state change

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, state

I have a problem with the triggering of a Hook `useEffect()` which has state as a dependency but is not called when the state change.

In my example I change the value of day_1 and day_2 with the decrease_day function, and the value is changed correctly. But even if day_1 and day_2 are changed, the second `useEffect()` (which has day_1 and day_2 as dependency) is never called when decrease_day() is called.

The weirdest thing is that this `UseEffec()` is released once, when day_1 and day_2 is changed by the first `useEffect()` which is fired on the initial render.

Here is a simplified extract of my code:

```
export default function Calendrier() {  

  useEffect(() => { //Hook which is fired on the initial render

    setday_1(moment(new Date()).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));

    setday_2(moment(moment(new Date()).add(1, 'days')).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));

  }, []);

  useEffect(() => { // Problem is here, this Hook is ONLY call when day_1 and day_2 are changed by the first useEffect
    
   console.log('is called ?')
   
  }, [day_1, day_2]);

  function decrease_day () {
    setday_1(moment(diminution_day_1_pour_calculs).format("DD/MM/YYYY")) //this never fire the second useEffect(), but day_1 is really changed

    setday_2( moment(diminution_day_2_pour_calculs).format("DD/MM/YYYY"))
  }


  const [day_1, setday_1] = useState('') 
  const [day_2, setday_2] = useState('') 

  return (
        <View style={styles.principal}>             
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.icon_day_1} onPress={decrease_day}/>
              <View style={styles.text_day_1}>
                <Text >{day_1}</Text>
              </View>
            <View style={styles.day_2}>
              <View style={styles.text_day_2}>
                <Text >{day_2}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
        </View>
  );
}
```

so how to trigger the second `useEffect()` at each change of state day_1 and day_2 ?

(I know there is a question with same title but it's not the same problem)

Comment: What are `diminution_day_1_pour_calculs` etc? Presumably they're defined outside the component so they'll be the same on each render - therefore `decrease_day` won't actually change anything, at least not after the first time it's called.

Comment: You've defined `day_1` and `setday_1` (the same goes for `2`) after you've used them (`useEffect(.., [day_1, day_2])`). That will generate an error.